# Interaction between templates and overloads

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, overload-resolution, argument-dependent-lookup

The output of the following code is `TA`, but I don't understand why.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};

template<typename T>
void fun(T) {
    std::cout << "T";
}

template<typename T>
void caller(T t) {
    fun(A{});
    fun(t);
}

void fun(A) {
    std::cout << "A";
}

int main() {
    caller(A{});
}
```

My understanding of templates tells me the following:

- just before the body of `main` is parsed, the only function "in place" is the non-template overload of `fun`, the one printing `A`, because the templates `fun` and `caller` have not been used and, in turn, instantiated;
- only when the call to `caller` is parsed, is the template `caller` instantiated with `T = A`, which implies that `caller` calls `fun` with objects of the same type in the two cases;
- furthermore, since that type is `A`, I'd say that the non-template overload of `fun` is called in both cases.

However, the above is wrong, otherwise I would get `AA` (actually, also `TT` would surprise me less than `TA`).

I've also noted that moving the non-template overload before the definition of `caller`, the output becomes `AA`, so I can only make this conjecture:

- when the parser reads the line `fun(A{});` the `fun` template is instantiated with `T = A`, even though the template `caller` is not being instatiated yet;
- then, when `caller(A{});` is parsed, `caller` is instantiated;
- only at this point the second call to `fun` in the body of `caller` can be interpreted as a call with an argument of type `A`, but this time the non-template `fun` is already known to the compiler, hence it's chosen as a better match.

I don't know if the above makes any sense, though.

More predictably, if if I use the following template specialization

```cpp
template<>
void fun<A>(A) {
    std::cout << "A";
}
```

***instead of*** the non-template overload, then output is always `AA`, regardless of whether I put the specialization before or after `caller`'s definition.

Comment: Don’t think of this in terms of time, but space: nom-dependent calls do lookup from where they appear (only), and so consider only earlier declarations.

Comment: Replacing non-template overload with template specialization, while still keeping that specialization below `fun(A{})` call, is either undefined behavior or ill-formed NDR, I suspect. Specializations must be declared before the first call that would have used one had it been visible, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I think you're right: the _In detail_ section [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) confirms it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fun(A{});` doesn't involve any template parameter-dependent expressions, and so the lookup and overload resolution occurs at the point of definition. At that point, only `fun(T)` is visible; `fun(A)` does not participate in overload resolution.

`fun(t)` call depends on `T`, and so the resolution is delayed to the point of instantiation. At that point, both `fun(A)` and `fun(T)` are visible, and `fun(A)` wins: non-templates are preferred over templates, other things equal.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Igor Tandetnik answer: if you delay instantiation by providing fake parameters, the overload resolution is delayed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};

template<typename T>
void fun(T) {
    std::cout << "T";
}

template<typename T, typename AA = A> // <<==== HERE
void caller(T t) {
    fun(AA{});
    fun(t);
}

void fun(A) {
    std::cout << "A";
}

int main() {
    caller(A{}); // Does AA
}
```

This is a common trick to delay resolution of otherwise template parameter-independent expressions, for example adding fake parameters to templates to prevent specializations from being full, for example:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {};

template<>
struct foo<void> {}; // Instantiated immediately

template<typename T, int fake = 0>
struct bar {};

template<int fake>
struct bar<void, fake> {}; // Not instantiated until used

// Users of bar<T> almost never realize they use bar<T, 0>, you can even provide a wrapper without `int` parameter.
```

Sometimes you need to access template class member with `this->` to force them being dependant too, etc.