# Template deduction depends on another template deduction

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, c++20, function-templates-overloading

Since `std::format` isn't supported everywhere, and I didn't want another large dependency like `fmt`, I wanted to quickly roll my own `to_string` solution for a number of types. The following is the code.

```
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
#include <concepts>

template<typename Type>
constexpr std::string stringify(const Type &data) noexcept;

template<typename Type> requires std::integral<Type>
constexpr std::string stringify(const Type &data) noexcept {
    return std::to_string(data);
}

template<typename Type>
constexpr std::string stringify_inner(const Type &data) noexcept {
    return stringify(data);
}

template<typename Type> requires std::ranges::range<Type>
constexpr std::string stringify_inner(const Type &data) noexcept {
    return "[" + stringify(data) + "]";
}

template<typename Type> requires std::ranges::range<Type>
constexpr std::string stringify(const Type &data) noexcept {
    std::string string;
    for (auto &i : data) {
        string += stringify_inner(i);
        string += ", ";
    }

    string.pop_back();
    string.pop_back();
    return string;
}
```

Now, if I write the following code, I get some nice output.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> b = {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }};
    std::cout << stringify(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << stringify(b) << std::endl;
}

// >>> 1, 2, 3, 4
// >>> [1, 2], [3, 4]
```

Now, for some reason, if I remove the `stringify<std::vector<int>>` call, the compiler fails to deduce the correct function.

```
int main() {
    // std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> b = {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }};
    // std::cout << stringify(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << stringify(b) << std::endl;
}

// >>> undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
// >>> std::allocator<char> > stringify<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >(std::vector<int,
// >>> std::allocator<int> > const&)'
```

I think I understand what is happening here, but I don't know why exactly or how to fix it. It seems like the compiler needs the manual instantiation of `stringify<std::vector<int>>`, so that it can resolve `stringify<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>`.

I've never encountered this behavior before and have no idea how to continue. I'm compiling with C++20, using GCC on Windows. Thanks.

Comment: Forward declaring your last function before `stringify_inner` will likely fix the issue. `stringify_inner` only knows about the specialisation for integral types so assumes the unimplemented first declaration is the one it should use

Comment: Clangd does give a warning for this: `inline function 'stringify<std::vector<int>>' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]`.

Comment: @Enlico The warning is valid, however, it does not appear to affect the code. I'm actually not sure how to get rid of that warning other than removing `constexpr` but that's a problem for another time.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm not sure what you mean. I have already "forward declared" the base template function. If you mean `stringify<std::vector<int>>` specifically, I would think that would defeat the purpose using `std::ranges::range<T>` to get any valid ranges.

Comment: No, i mean forward declare the specialisation

Comment: @JeJo EDIT: I misread your answer. I understand why it might be easier to implement this using a single function, but I think as there are more corner cases to deal with such as containers of containers or tuples which require recursive unwrapping, a single function may be more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of declarations of your template overloads results in

```
template<typename Type> requires std::ranges::range<Type>
constexpr std::string stringify(const Type& data) noexcept;
```

being for the overload, when specializing

```
template<typename Type> requires std::ranges::range<Type>
constexpr std::string stringify_inner(const Type &data) noexcept {
    return "[" + stringify(data) + "]";
}
```

with `Type = std::vector<int>`, but this function isn't defined anywhere. You need to make sure to declare the function signature for ranges early enough for the compiler to use it:

```
template<typename Type>
constexpr std::string stringify(const Type& data) noexcept;

template<typename Type> requires std::integral<Type>
constexpr std::string stringify(const Type& data) noexcept {
    return std::to_string(data);
}

/////////////////////// Add this ////////////////////////////////////
template<typename Type> requires std::ranges::range<Type>
constexpr std::string stringify(const Type& data) noexcept;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename Type>
constexpr std::string stringify_inner(const Type& data) noexcept {
    return stringify(data);
}

template<typename Type> requires std::ranges::range<Type>
constexpr std::string stringify_inner(const Type& data) noexcept {
    return "[" + stringify(data) + "]";
}

template<typename Type> requires std::ranges::range<Type>
constexpr std::string stringify(const Type& data) noexcept {
    std::string string;
    for (auto& i : data) {
        string += stringify_inner(i);
        string += ", ";
    }

    string.pop_back();
    string.pop_back();
    return string;
}
template<typename Type> requires std::ranges::range<Type>
constexpr std::string stringify(const Type& data) noexcept;

template<typename Type>
constexpr std::string stringify_inner(const Type& data) noexcept {
    return stringify(data);
}

template<typename Type> requires std::ranges::range<Type>
constexpr std::string stringify_inner(const Type& data) noexcept {
    return "[" + stringify(data) + "]";
}

template<typename Type> requires std::ranges::range<Type>
constexpr std::string stringify(const Type& data) noexcept {
    std::string string;
    for (auto& i : data) {
        string += stringify_inner(i);
        string += ", ";
    }

    string.pop_back();
    string.pop_back();
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thanks for the answer. I guess it's probably a guess idea to forward declare every unique `stringify ... requires` clause here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is typed in prose on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)

> Specialization must be declared before the first use that would cause implicit instantiation

In your example, the specialization of `stringify` for `range`s would be instatiated by the call to the first of `stringify_inner`'s overload, but it is declared after it, instead of before.

---

As often happens, we could have got some insight by seeing what clang thinks about the code

> ```
> Clangd does give a warning for this: `inline function 'stringify<std::vector<int>>' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]`.
> constexpr std::string stringify(const Type &data) noexcept;
>                      ^
> somesource.cpp:22:18: note: used here
>    return "[" + stringify(data) + "]";
>                 ^
> 1 warning generated.
> ```

which would have at least been clearer than GCC's.

---

[Related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450116/interaction-between-templates-and-overloads) and [related comment on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69221487/msvc-using-namespace-directive-in-caller-of-generic-lambda-leaks-into-the-lamb/69227482#comment122366018_69227482).

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have mentioned the issue with overloading and function declaration issues.

(For future readers) I propose having the stringifying in a single (recursive) function, which take care the ranges, and the `std::integral`(or `is_stringable`) overload can be kept for integral types.

Something like as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
using namespace std::string_literals;

template<typename Type> // concept for checking std::to_string-able types
concept is_stringable = requires (Type t) 
            { {std::to_string(t) }->std::same_as<std::string>; };

// "stringify" overload for is_stringable
constexpr std::string stringify(const is_stringable auto& data) {
    return std::to_string(data);
}

// "stringify" overload for ranges
constexpr std::string stringify(const std::ranges::range auto& data) {
    // value type of the ranges (Only Sequence ranges)
    using ValueType = std::remove_const_t<
        std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*data.cbegin())>
    >;

    if constexpr (is_stringable<ValueType>) {
        std::string string{};
        for (ValueType element : data)
            string += stringify(element) + ", "s;
        string.pop_back();
        string.pop_back();
        return "["s + string + "]"s;
    }
    // else if constexpr (<other types Ex. ValueType == std::tuple>) {}
    // .... more
    else {
        std::string string;
        for (const ValueType& innerRange : data)
            string += stringify(innerRange);
        return string;
    }
}
```

[See live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/csfcGPc4x)